# Delphi XE5 Union declaration Namespaces in uses

Tags: delphi, namespaces, declaration

Is there a way to declare only namespace in uses and delphi get automaticaly all units with it?

For expamle:

```
MyNamespace.Unit2.pas
MyNameSpace.Unit3.pas

unit Unit1
uses MyNameSpace;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to declare only namespace in uses and delphi get automaticaly all units with it?

No. You have to name each unit that you wish to use.

Comment: OK. Thanks for fast answer. This may by is for protection or just a stupid decision. Nooow, i must declare about 50 units and that is not all at this stage :D

Comment: Well, you only need to use the ones that you need. And remember that when you use a unit you merge all of its public symbols into the using unit's namespace and silently hide any symbols with the same name. Importing units is a sledgehammer. Importing units en masse is possibly not a great idea on balance.